# Log analytics Post call 403 forbidden error

Tags: httpclient, azure-log-analytics

Following is the below code sample that am trying to post data to log analytics , but failing with forbidden error.
Able to post the data with postasync call successfully, but when using with sendasync i see this error, I want to use sendasync for meeting other requirements in the project, please let me know if there is anything am missing to update or any suggestions that could help me unblocked

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SyncServiceMonitoringToLA
{
    class Program
    {

        // An example JSON object, with key/value pairs
        static string json = @"[{""DemoField1"":""DemoValue1"",""DemoField2"":""DemoValue2""},{""DemoField3"":""DemoValue3"",""DemoField4"":""DemoValue4""}]";

        // Update customerId to your Log Analytics workspace ID
        static string customerId = "xxx";

        // For sharedKey, use either the primary or the secondary Connected Sources client authentication key   
        static string sharedKey = "xxx";

        // LogName is name of the event type that is being submitted to Azure Monitor
        static string LogName = "syncmgTest";

        // You can use an optional field to specify the timestamp from the data. If the time field is not specified, Azure Monitor assumes the time is the message ingestion time
        static string TimeStampField = "";

        static void Main()
        {
            // Create a hash for the API signature
            var datestring = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("r");
            var jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            string stringToHash = "POST\n" + jsonBytes.Length + "\napplication/json\n" + "x-ms-date:" + datestring + "\n/api/logs";
            string hashedString = BuildSignature(stringToHash, sharedKey);
            string signature = "SharedKey " + customerId + ":" + hashedString;

            //Console.WriteLine("" + PostData(signature, datestring, json));
            PostData(signature, datestring, json);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // Build the API signature
        public static string BuildSignature(string message, string secret)
        {
            var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] keyByte = Convert.FromBase64String(secret);
            byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
            using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
            {
                byte[] hash = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
            }
        }

        // Send a request to the POST API endpoint
        public static async void PostData(string signature, string date, string json)
        {
            try
            { 
                System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json"); 
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("log-type", "syncmgTest");


                string url = "https://" + customerId + ".ods.opinsights.azure.com/api/logs?api-version=2016-04-01";

                var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var httpmsg = new HttpRequestMessage();
                string requestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                httpmsg.Headers.Add("Authorization", signature);
                httpmsg.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", date);
                httpmsg.Content = content;
                httpmsg.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                httpmsg.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
                var response =  await client.SendAsync(httpmsg);

                Console.WriteLine(response);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception excep)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("API Post Exception: " + excep.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if you're using the real customerId  and sharedKey. If they are real, please delete this post, and post a new one without the real customerId and sharedKey.

Comment: they are not real , i placed 'XXX' to replace with actual value, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Hi, you'd better delete this post and post a new issue, because someone can see the edit information so they can get your personal information.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing this:

```
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

With this:

```
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
```

Comment: I am not the owner of this question so I can't mark it as solved but for anyone looking at this, this might solve your issue since it solved mine